# Is it possible to make a label with underline and arrow from label to the point in GeoServer's SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

It is commonly a problem when you need all points to be labelled, but due to high density of points it is difficult to understand the ties between points and labels. Arrows would be a way, but I haven't found anything similar even in SLD extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is normally called a "leader line", e.g.:

[image]

Unfortunately GeoServer does not support them, but if you really need them there you can follow this guide:

https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.ianturton.com/geoserver/styling/2016/03/15/Leader-lines.html) about how to do this a while ago. Basically you can use the [Easy Custom Labelling](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/) plugin to create the leader lines and then save them (and the labels) as a shapefile to load into QGIS.

[image]

Comment: so to this moment leading lines should be shapes themselves? not sure it would be okay on the different scales...

Comment: you can turn them on and off with scale